# PHP/MYSQL Inline editing after type password

Tags: php, mysql, inline, editing

I want to create simple CMS that would allow editing the site in place (inline editing).

What I've done:

1. Login panel on PHP and MySQL
2. Editing page with inline editor BootStrap WyswiHTML5
3. Fully working saving and reading from MySQL via WyswiHTML5

But, now we have a site that is only read tables from MySQL for normal user.
And the second is mirror site first with added BootStrap WyswiHTML5, where Admin can change content of site first.

So it very annoyingly that I must have mirrored site...
I have idea that if we go to url: http://example.com/admin, we have a login forms. If password is correct then redirect us to the first (and only one) page, but with some value.

On this site will be a if function and if we logged then editor are enabled.

It's simple to write here that, but i have no idea how to do that. Maybe more experienced members of StackOverflow could help me.

Comment: Hey Geek, what have you done?

Comment: As i said, login forms but after login redirect to the second site, reading and writing to mysql via wyswihtml5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not implement a login check with PHP ?

Save the login-state in the PHP $_SESSION variable after login.

Check this variable on the regular website.
If an Admin is logged in you could just print out the HTML code for your wysiwyg,
make an page redirect, or whatever you prefer.

Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php